# NLog target database not working in ASP NET Core 2.2 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, nlog, asp.net-core-2.2

I have been dealing with NLog for 2 days but it does not record to the database and I downloaded the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` packages from the nuget service but it does not work.

This is my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
      <target name="db"
              xsi:type="Database"
              dbProvider="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"
              connectionString="server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=blog;integrated security=True;"
              commandType="StoredProcedure"
              commandText="[dbo].[NLog_AddEntry_p]"
        >
          <parameter name="@machineName"    layout="${machinename}" />
          <parameter name="@logged"         layout="${date}" />
          <parameter name="@level"          layout="${level}" />
          <parameter name="@message"        layout="${message}" />
          <parameter name="@logger"         layout="${logger}" />
          <parameter name="@properties"     layout="${all-event-properties:separator=|}" />
          <parameter name="@callsite"       layout="${callsite}" />
          <parameter name="@exception"      layout="${exception:tostring}" />
      </target>
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="db" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="db" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And this is my `Program.cs` file:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        // NLog: setup the logger first to catch all errors
        var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();

        try
        {
            logger.Debug("init main");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //NLog: catch setup errors
            logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
    })
    .UseNLog();  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection

}
```

Application.json

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
```

Finally my database code (I copied from nlog wiki):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NLog] 
(
   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [MachineName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
   [Logged] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [Level] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
   [Message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
   [Logger] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
   [Properties] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
   [Callsite] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
   [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Log] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) 
                   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                         IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                         ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NLog_AddEntry_p] 
(
  @machineName nvarchar(200),
  @logged datetime,
  @level varchar(5),
  @message nvarchar(max),
  @logger nvarchar(300),
  @properties nvarchar(max),
  @callsite nvarchar(300),
  @exception nvarchar(max)
) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[NLog] ([MachineName], [Logged], [Level], [Message],
                              [Logger], [Properties], [Callsite], [Exception])
    VALUES (@machineName, @logged, @level, @message,
            @logger, @properties, @callsite, @exception);
END
```

Comment: do you see any errors in c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt this is the nlog internal logs

Comment: Yes indeed, check the internal log. If that won't help, check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

I see in the internal log file (As Warn level...) that [NLog.Database](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Database/) extensions is missing,
I install the package by NuGet and add to extensions section in my **nlog.config** file and the problem was resolved

```
<extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
        <add assembly="NLog.Database" />
</extensions>
```

Hopes its help you too.